# Azure AD doesn't grant offline_access

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to log in users into my application with Azure AD, but I cannot get offline_access permission (scope) on my server.

My initial request is:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fservice%2Emyserver%2Ecz&scope=user.read%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&response_mode=form_post&state=azure_login
```

As you can see I ask for `user.read`, `openid`, `profile` and `offline_access`. But when I get the token, the response is:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "profile openid email User.Read",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "ey...",
    "id_token": "ey..."
}
```

First of all I didn't ask for email and secondly there isn't `refresh_token` and `expires_on`.

Most interestingly, if I run the application locally on my computer(redirect_uri is http://localhost:8080) I get entirely different response:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1568980038",
    "access_token": "AQ...",
    "refresh_token": "AQ...",
    "id_token": "ey..."
}
```

Locally I have `offline_access` permission, on the other hand I don't have any other permission. For instance I cannot access `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` from http://localhost:8080 .

What I have to do in order to get `offline_access` permission on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've finally found it. The whole problem was caused by the combination of API. There are following links:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

And I've overlooked 'v2.0' and mixed them together.